# How to run personal.xlsb macro using vba to export data to mysql

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

Is this set of code is correct to be run on personal.xlsb (MS Excel) and can fully transport the data to mysql? This is because I keep getting blank rows when I execute such code. This seems not to work since active sheet here keeps referring to my personal.xlsb and not the other excel file containing the data that I am planning to export the data with, as both excel files (data & personal.xlsb) are opened at the same time but personal.xlsb file is at the front while the data excel file at the back.

```
Public Sub Insert_Testing()
Dim con as adodb.connection
Dim lastrow as long
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set con = New Adodb.connection
Con.open = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;Data Source=MySQL_db;"
Dim rng as range
Lastrow = ws.Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
Set rng = ws.Range("A2:G" & Lastrow)
Dim row as range

For each row in rng.rows
  SQL = "Insert into skynet_msa.ALU_testing (Area, Min_C, Max_C, Avg_C, Emis, Ta_C, Area_Px) values ('" & row.Cells(1).Value & "', '" & row.Cells(2).Value & "', '" & row.Cells(3).Value & "', '" & row.Cells(4).Value & "', '" & row.Cells(5).Value & "', '" & row.Cells(6).Value & "', '" & row.Cells(7).Value &"');"
  Con.Execute SQL
Next row

Con.close
MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

This is the code I run from VBScript to launch the two excel files (personal.xlsb and the data)

```
sPath = "H:\msa\Temp\MengKeat\FlukeReport\20220429\CV4T1L2.11\testing1"

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

sNewestFile = GetNewestFile(sPath)

If sNewestFile <> "" Then

WScript.Echo "Newest file is " & sNewestFile

dFileModDate = oFSO.GetFile(sNewestFile).DateLastModified
If DateDiff("h", dFileModDate, Now) > 24 Then
End If

Else
WScript.Echo "Directory is empty"
End If

Function GetNewestFile(ByVal sPath)

sNewestFile = Null ' init value

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(sPath)
Set oFiles = oFolder.Files

For Each oFile In oFiles
On Error Resume Next
If IsNull(sNewestFile) Then
sNewestFile = oFile.Path
dPrevDate = oFile.DateLastModified
Elseif dPrevDate < oFile.DateLastModified Then
sNewestFile = oFile.Path
End If
On Error Goto 0
Next

If IsNull(sNewestFile) Then sNewestFile = ""

GetNewestFile = sNewestFile

ExcelFilePath = sNewestFile

MacroPath = "C:\Users\gsumarlin\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART\PERSONAL.XLSB"

MacroName = "PERSONAL.XLSB!Module1.Insert_Testing"

Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

ExcelApp.Visible = "False"

ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = False

Set wb = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(ExcelFilePath)

ExcelApp.Application.Visible = True

Set mac = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(MacroPath)

ExcelApp.Run MacroName

wb.Save

ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = True

MsgBox "Your Automated Task successfully ran at " & TimeValue(Now), vbInformation

oFSO.DeleteFile sNewestFile
Set oFSO = Nothing  

End Function
```

Comment: `ThisWorkbook` is the workbook where the code is stored. If your code is in personal.xlsb, `ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet` will use the "active" sheet of personal. You need to specify either name of the Workbook of simply use `Set ws = ActiveSheet` when you want to access the active sheet (the visible sheet)

Comment: but there are 2 active sheets the personal sheet and the data sheet. How do i know whether the code refers to the data sheet?

Comment: There is one real "active" worksheet, that is the sheet where the focus is on (with other words, If you start typing, the keys are send to this sheet). Writing `Set ws = ActiveSheet` will set the variable `ws` to that sheet. Additionally, every workbook has an active sheet, that is the sheet that would get the focus if you select the workbook window from your taskbar. If you want to select any other sheet, you need to tell VBA which exactly you want, eg `Set ws = Workbooks("test123.xlsx").sheets("Sheet1")`.

Comment: But I am running a programme for random uploaded files throughout the day so I won't know the name of each workbook uploaded, hence, i cannot use the method you suggested. and sorry i was talking abt different workbooks (files) and sheets not just different sheets but one workbook.

Comment: do you know any idea how to solve this?

Comment: How are those workbooks opened? Via code? Then assign the workbook to a variable when opening it.

Comment: Using vbscript. I use 2 variable to assign the directories of 2 files. So i just substitute the worksheets’ names w variables?

Comment: so to clarify, there are two workbooks opened up at the same time: one is personal.xlsb containing the macro that can be used for other excel files but has no data, and the other one (called data excel file) containing the data but without any macro. I want to use the macro from personal.xlsb to be used for the data excel file containing the data. Is it possible to do this? (and the vbscript i just added above)